# Importing java classes in Matlab

Tags: java, matlab, protocol-buffers

I have generated some Java classes from a proto file. Just to be sure I did not make mistakes: I first compiled the proto file using protoc and then compiled the generated java file using javac.

I am trying to import the classes I generated in Matlab, but I kept getting the error:

```
Error using javaMethod No class MyClass can be located on the Java class path
```

I modified the classpath.txt in Matlab, adding both the directory containing the java classes and the path to the jar file itself. I checked and I believe that the java version I am using to compile the java classes is the same as the one Matlab uses.

Any idea? I do not manage to make sense of it..  :(

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

MATLAB misleadingly produces the `No class MyClass can be located on the Java class path` error when the classfiles are not compatible with the embedded JVM.  Make sure the Java classfiles you're trying to use do not target a newer JVM.  You can use `version -java` to check MATLAB's JVM version.

R2007b:

```
>> version -java

ans =

Java 1.6.0 with Sun Microsystems Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode
```

R2014b-Prerelease:

```
>> version -java

ans =

Java 1.7.0_11-b21 with Oracle Corporation Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM mixed mode
```

If your classfiles were compiled with a newer JDK, you'll need to recompile them.  You can either use an older, compatible JDK; or you can use your newer JDK but run `javac` with the `-source`, `-target`, and `-bootclasspath` options to target the older MATLAB JVM.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. That's the java version running on Matlab: `Java 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609 with Apple Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM mixed mode` and this is the same I used to compile the java files (`java -version` from terminal gave the same result)

Comment: It is the same version apparently.

Comment: That's good news.  Double-check by running `javac -version` (instead of java -version), just in case the default JRE and JDK don't match.

Comment: I assume you already restarted MATLAB, and when you type `javaclasspath` on the MATLAB console, the directory or jarfile containing your Java classes is listed, correct?

Comment: yes, it is listed there and I restarted Matlab after any change I made.

Comment: Yikes, sorry for not replying again sooner.  Your classfiles are compatible with MATLAB's JVM, and you've added each jarfile and/or top-level directory to the beginning of classpath.txt and restarted MATLAB.  Normally that does the trick.  When you import, are you importing the fully-qualified classname?  (e.g., `import com.example.MyClass` rather than just `import MyClass`)  If all else fails, can you create a SCCE and add that to the question?